# JMeter: SSLManager.getPassword() - No password provided, and no GUI present so cannot prompt

Tags: jmeter, keystore

I am getting below error while running JMeter in non GUI mode in Linux OS, even though certificate(JKS) and password is provided in system.properties.

SSLManager.getPassword() - No password provided, and no GUI present so cannot prompt

I have verified the JKS certificate using keytool to ensure file is not corrupted and password is spelled correctly.

JMeter test works without issues in windows with same JKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager):

> The SSL Manager is a way to select a client certificate so that you can test applications that use Public Key Infrastructure (PKI). **It is only needed if you have not set up the appropriate System properties.**

So if you're running your test in command line non-GUI mode you need to:

1. Remove the SSL Manager from your Test Plan
2. Add the next lines to [*system.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/keystore
   javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your-keystore-password
   ```

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/client-side-performance-testing-using-jmeter)